# tomcat7 wont run on startup

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Tried everything but it just wont work, im running tomcat7 on an EC2 instance (amazon AWS). I can start up tomcat7 manually by starting startup.sh, but not automatically on startup. The error message I get in logs/catalina.out is the following:

```
/etc/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/bin/catalina.sh: 1: eval: /etc/jdk1.7.0_07/bin/java: not found
```

My enviroment variables are also setup properly:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME -> /etc/jdk1.7.0_07/bin/java
echo $PATH -> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin/:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/etc/jdk1.7.0_07/bin
```

I can also type "java -version" in shell getting proper output, however  "/etc/jdk1.7.0_07/bin/java -version" does not work and only returns "*No such file or directory*".

Im really not sure what to do now, feels like i tried everything, hope someone can help me!
Also the instance is running **Ubuntu server 12.04**.

Comment: setup JAVA_HOME in your `/etc/bash.bashrc` and your  java home should be `$JAVA_HOME -> /etc/jdk1.7.0_07` not until bin

Comment: Try `which java` in your shell to see which `java` binary it's using. The script used to start Tomcat may also be using a different java than `/etc/jdk..`.

Comment: Try to use [Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/), which will do all this setup work for you automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `sudo su vi /etc/bash.bashrc` and copy following

```
JAVA_HOME=/etc/jdk1.7.0_07 //you have to only specify path until java dir not bin
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

Comment: still getting the same error, however "which java" returns "/usr/bin/java", should i change this, and if so how do i do that?

Comment: @Marcus There is another java on your machine have you saved the file properly. Also try after restarting.

Comment: i did reboot, now not even manual start of tomcat7 works, i get the following error when running startup.sh manually: "./catalina.sh 1: eval: /etc/jdk1.7.0_07/bin/java: not found" (in catalina.out log file)

Comment: @Marcus Which means you do not have such jdk existing on your machine. you can try `locate jdk` to find where is the jdk location

Comment: Thank you, through "locate jdk" i found the pre-installed jdk that was on the machine which I didnt know existed. I changed JAVA_HOME to "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64" and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

I do not particularly known about specifics of ubuntu+tomcat7 on EC2. So my answer could be missing a point a bit. It is given from generic ubuntu point of view.

Possibly things will be a bit easier to manage if you use apt-get to manage tomcat and java on ubuntu. In that case the tomcat will automatically started on start up. The commands below are tested on ubuntu 12.10, but also worked on some earlier version.

To install Java you need the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

If the first command fails, use the following:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

Then install tomcat7 using:

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```

After that you need to tell tomcat to use installed java 7. For that purpose modify /etc/default/tomcat7 file either manually or using command like the following:

```
cat /etc/default/tomcat7 | sed 's/#JAVA_HOME=\/usr\/lib\/jvm\/openjdk-6-jdk/JAVA_HOME=\/usr\/lib\/jvm\/java-7-oracle/' >/tmp/tomcat7-updated
sudo cp /tmp/tomcat7-updated /etc/default/tomcat7
```

After that tomcat should load on start up. You just need to tune up ports and other configuration information. Note that this tomcat uses /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ to store web applications. You could also start or stop tomcat manually using the commands like the following:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat7 start
```

Answer (score 0):

For automatic startup of tomcat, it should be started during booting time only.

For that you need to write a script which starts the tomcat and put this file in the etc/init.d or you can put it for different runlevels.

Answer (score 0):

The hint for me was modifying the shell script file (set JAVA_HOME variable) and this resolved the issue.

The tomcat script file is generally under ***/etc/init.d/*** directory